# Set up a VPN server that reroutes all traffic

Tags: networking, vpn

I am on mobile so sorry if this question is asked before.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and would like to do the following:

It runs a service for VPN server using commonly used protocol by Windows.

Then it reroute all traffic on the VPN through a local proxy server.

So the system is like this:

Client --> VPN --> Proxy --> Internet

And the VPN and proxy are both on the Raspberry Pi, and it is in a local network.

This is for practical reasons. Specifically, I need to use a software called Shadowsocks to connect to the Internet, which acts like a Socks proxy server. But not all applications use system proxy settings and I would like to force all applications to use the proxy. So I need a VPN. And I would like to modify my local clients as little as possible.

Thanks for any suggestions. I don't know where to start.